# Send data to only new clients with Socket.io?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

i'm working on a radio server. i need to send the playlist to each new user,

i tried this, but sent to all users when a new user connects.

```
io.on('connected',function(socket) {
 io.emit('playlist',playlist);
});
```

I want to send only new users, How can I do?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send  event to current socket

```
io.on('connection',function(socket) {
 socket.emit('playlist',playlist);
});
```

Comment: each user should have the same playlist, must submit a new data every 2 minutes

Comment: you can call the http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#server#emit every 2 minutes to notify all connected users with even't of playlist